# Using assert_eq or printing large fixed sized arrays doesn't work

Tags: arrays, rust, slice, assert

I have written some tests where I need to assert that two arrays are equal. Some arrays are `[u8; 48]` while others are `[u8; 188]`:

```
#[test]
fn mul() {
    let mut t1: [u8; 48] = [0; 48];
    let t2: [u8; 48] = [0; 48];

    // some computation goes here.

    assert_eq!(t1, t2, "\nExpected\n{:?}\nfound\n{:?}", t2, t1);
}
```

I get multiple errors here:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `[u8; 48]`
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     assert_eq!(t1, t2, "\nExpected\n{:?}\nfound\n{:?}", t2, t1);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `[u8; 48]`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8; 48]: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:57
  |
8 |     assert_eq!(t1, t2, "\nExpected\n{:?}\nfound\n{:?}", t2, t1);
  |                                                         ^^ `[u8; 48]` cannot be formatted using `:?`; if it is defined in your crate, add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement it
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `[u8; 48]`
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
```

Trying to print them as slices like `t2[..]` or `t1[..]` doesn't seem to work.

How do I use `assert` with these arrays and print them?

Comment: You have to assert for each element individually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the comparison part you can just convert the arrays to iterators and compare elementwise.

```
assert_eq!(t1.len(), t2.len(), "Arrays don't have the same length");
assert!(t1.iter().zip(t2.iter()).all(|(a,b)| a == b), "Arrays are not equal");
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the arrays have different size and they are different only after the last element of the shortest array. It's fine if the PO is absolutely sure they will only ever have two `[T; N]` with the same `N`, but if it ever changes that's going to be a tricky bug to find.

Comment: @mcarton True, I added another assertion for that to my answer.

Comment: There is also [`itertools::Itertools::all_equal`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.4/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.all_equal) which does just that.

Comment: There's also [`Iterator::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq)

Answer (score 10):

With [`Iterator::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq), it is possible to compare anything that can be turned into an iterator for equality:

```
let mut t1: [u8; 48] = [0; 48];
let t2: [u8; 48] = [0; 48];
assert!(t1.iter().eq(t2.iter()));
```

Answer (score 7):

## Using slices

As a workaround, you can just use **`&t1[..]`** (instead of `t1[..]`) to make arrays into slices. You'll have to do this for **both comparison and formatting**.

```
assert_eq!(&t1[..], &t2[..], "\nExpected\n{:?}\nfound\n{:?}", &t2[..], &t1[..]);
```

or

```
assert_eq!(t1[..], t2[..], "\nExpected\n{:?}\nfound\n{:?}", &t2[..], &t1[..]);
```

## Formatting arrays directly

Ideally, the original code should compile, but it doesn't for now. The reason is that the standard library [implements common traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) (such as [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) and [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html)) for arrays of **only up to 32 elements**, due to [lack of const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580).

Therefore, you can compare and format shorter arrays like:

```
let t1: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
let t2: [u8; 32] = [1; 32];
assert_eq!(t1, t2, "\nExpected\n{:?}\nfound\n{:?}", t2, t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `Vec`s out of them.

```
fn main() {
    let a: [u8; 3] = [0, 1, 2];
    let b: [u8; 3] = [2, 3, 4];
    let c: [u8; 3] = [0, 1, 2];

    let va: Vec<u8> = a.to_vec();
    let vb: Vec<u8> = b.to_vec();
    let vc: Vec<u8> = c.to_vec();

    println!("va==vb {}", va == vb);
    println!("va==vc {}", va == vc);
    println!("vb==vc {}", vb == vc);
}
```

Comment: `vec!(a)` will make a one-element vector, that one element being a slice. These inner-slices then compare because their length is less than 32.

Comment: Thanks.  Changed it to `to_vec()`.

Comment: While technically correct, I would not recommend this answer as-is because it needlessly allocates memory to create the `Vec`.